# Filtering associated polymorphic models

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, polymorphic-associations

I have `Favorite` model which allows `Entries` and `Feeds` to be saved by users.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :favorites
   has_many :favorite_feeds, :through =>  :favorites, :source => :favorable, :source_type => "Feed"
   has_many :favorite_entries, :through =>  :favorites, :source => :favorable, :source_type => "Entry"
 end

 class Favorite < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :user
   belongs_to :favorable, :polymorphic => true
   attr_accessible :user, :favorable
 end

 class Feed < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :favorites, :as => :favorable
   has_many :fans, :through => :favorites, :source => :user
 end

 class Entry < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :favorites, :as => :favorable
   has_many :fans, :through => :favorites, :source => :user
 end
```

I now need to display ALL `Entries` on a page and indicate whether the `current_user` has added each `Entry` as a `favourite`. At the moment calling `@entry.fans` is fetching every `User` from the database, which is inefficient. I need a way of filtering this call to only fetch favorites that belong to the `current_user` since I don't need any of the other records.

I can do this in memory in my controller, but I'm thinking there is a way to simply select the `current_user`s favorites and join it to the `Entries` model using Active::Record.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Controller:

```
@entries = Entry.all
@user_favorite_entry_ids = current_user.favorite_entries.pluck(:id)
```

View:

```
<% @entries.each do |entry| %>
<%= @entry.id %>: <%= @entry.id.in?(@user_favorite_entry_ids) ? 'favorite of current user' : 'not' %>
<% end %>
```

Or, if you really like doing things in the database:

```
@entries = Entry.select('entries.*, count(favorites.id) as current_user_favorite').joins("left join favorites on favorites.favorable_id = entries.id and favorites.favorable_type = 'Entry' and favorites.user_id = #{current_user.id}")
```

and then:

```
<% @entries.each do |entry| %>
  <%= @entry.id %>: <%= (@entry.current_user_favorite.to_i > 0) ? 'favorite of current user' : 'not' %>
<% end %>
```